# D3: Not able to parse dates with year-month

Tags: javascript, parsing, d3.js

For some reason my bars (rects) are drawing really wide- I think its because the dates are not parsing correctly. here is the code

```
var fakeData= [
    {"date":2013-10,"shortFig":10},
    {"date":2013-11,"shortFig":-15},
    {"date":2013-12,"shortFig":15},
    {"date":2014-01,"shortFig":39},
    {"date":2014-02,"shortFig":-38},
    {"date":2014-03,"shortFig":33},
    {"date":2014-04,"shortFig":-35},
    {"date":2014-05,"shortFig":-2},
    {"date":2014-06,"shortFig":-39},
    {"date":2014-07,"shortFig":-46},
    {"date":2014-08,"shortFig":23},
    {"date":2014-09,"shortFig":45}
]
```

..this data becomes "thedata" in my chart building function where I try to parse the data and build the x scales and x axis:

```
            // parse dates
            var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y–%m").parse;

            thedata.forEach(function(d) {

                var date = d.date.toString();

                d.date = parseDate(date);
            }); 

            //The X scale
            var xScale=d3.scale.ordinal()
                .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1)
                .domain(thedata.map(function(d) { return d.date; }));

            //With the X scale, set up the X axis
            var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(xScale)
                .orient("bottom")
                .tickValues([thedata[0].date]);             

            //Call the X axis
            baseGroup.append("g")
                  .attr("class", "xaxis")
                  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                  .call(xAxis);

            baseGroup.selectAll("rect")
                    .data(thedata)
                    .enter()
                    .append("rect")
                    .attr("class", function(d){ if(d.shortFig >= 0){return "green3"}else{return "red3"} })
                    .attr({
                        "x": function(d) {return xScale(d.date);},  
                        "y": function(d) {return yScale(Math.max(0, d.shortFig));},  //Return the number with the highest value 
                        "height": function(d) {return Math.abs(yScale(d.shortFig) - yScale(0));}, //Return the absolute value of a number, so negative numbers will be positive
                        "width": xScale.rangeBand()
                    });
```

Comment: The value of `date` on each object should be a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a typo, the `date` parameters should be strings. Tested this, it works, just replace the `fakeData` array and you should be set.

```
var fakeData= [
    {"date":"2013-10","shortFig":10},
    {"date":"2013-11","shortFig":-15},
    {"date":"2013-12","shortFig":15},
    {"date":"2014-01","shortFig":39},
    {"date":"2014-02","shortFig":-38},
    {"date":"2014-03","shortFig":33},
    {"date":"2014-04","shortFig":-35},
    {"date":"2014-05","shortFig":-2},
    {"date":"2014-06","shortFig":-39},
    {"date":"2014-07","shortFig":-46},
    {"date":"2014-08","shortFig":23},
    {"date":"2014-09","shortFig":45}
];

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m").parse;

fakeData.forEach(function(d){
    console.log(parseDate(d.date));
});
```